# Handle textview that takes text from asynctask

Tags: android, string, sqlite, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I have a text view called tv that takes content from a web page. I want to store the content of that text view on button click but I don't want that the content of one day overwrite the content of the previous day ( for example today tv=ok and tomorrow tv=ok1 , I want to store ok and ok1 not only ok1)
Of course with shared preferences, I can store that text but I don't want to overwrite the text of the previous day

---

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oks);
                tv.setText(result[1].toString());

---

```
//in pass there is the text of tv(in main activity)

    SharedPreferences ok = getSharedPreferences("pass", 0);

    String str = ""+ok.getString("textvalue","");


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ok.edit();
    editor.putString("textvalue",str);
    editor.apply();


    TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.preferiti);




    textView.setText(ok.getString("textvalue",""));
```

---

Comment: If you are storing in sharedPref then get the value of it append your new value and store it again

Comment: I am a beginner in android can you show me an example? Thank you

Comment: Check this :- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences

Comment: Read from  String str = sharedPref.getString("YOUR_KEY","DEFAULT_VALUE")+"today value" now save str in your sharedprefence again

Comment: The last thing . For saving str in sharedpreference i have to use this method SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        str, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

Comment: You have to edit sharedPrefrence like this Editor editor =sharedPref.edit();

Comment: editor.putstring("mykey", str) doesn't work, I am a bit confused ....can you sum up all the passage here . Thank you so much, sorry if I don't understand but I am trying to do my best

Comment: did you apply the change ? like this editor.apply(); this will apply all your changes

Comment: can you add your save code to your question ?

Comment: yes of course...thank you

Comment: Maybe i miss something

Answer (score 0):

This is your textview

```
  //this are two fields which you want to append and getting somehow from API
 String todayTv="ok" , tomorrowTv="ok1";
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oks);
```

Let's set todayTv value on textView

```
 tv.setText(todayTv);
```

now you want to store this value

```
SharedPreference sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("pass", 0); 
Editor edit=sharedPref.edit(); 
edit.putString("textvalue",tv.getText().toString()); //getting value from textview 
edit.apply();
```

Saved ! lets say you have now tomorrowTv which you want to show with your previous result i.e like this ok ok1

```
 tv.setText(sharedPref.getString("textvalue","")+" "+tomorrowTv); //Concat strings and set text
```

Old Value -  sharedPref.getString("textvalue","")

New Value - tomorrowTv

Now save it again with the above code for future

```
SharedPreference sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("pass", 0); 
Editor edit=sharedPref.edit(); 
edit.putString("textvalue",tv.getText().toString()); //It will give you final string containg old and new value into one string
edit.apply();
```

Hope it will give you insight about It.

Read More : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: The only problem is that i don t have 2 separate string...I have only One string that is populated by an asynktask and It changes every day ..

Comment: maybe i can't with shared preferences , i have to use sq database ?

Comment: It depends upon your requirement, but if you want to store value from async task then store it directly in your shared pref. and retrieve it. Hope it helped you.